# how to send form saved data as mail attachment using content rule once the workflow sate is changed for it in Plone

Tags: python, plone, ploneformgen

I wish to send the data submitted using plone formgen as "mail attachment" for approval to a particular mail id. I use content rule for change in workflow state, to trigger the mail, stating that the data is ready for approval to the mail id. BUT I wish to mail the **data also** Using plone 4.1